# What is the difference between coherence and entanglement?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, coherence

I am confused to the two terms, my question is what is the difference between coherence and entanglement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coherence means particular type of correlation (of phase; say) between  two points on a wavefront or etc (see optics by Hecht); here two points "does not" reside in space-like separation [of course I am talking of one point at time t_1 and other point at time t_2; in the mean time signal has reached from point 1 to point 2: in this sense] & they can be causally related; their interaction is always of course sub-luminal.In the other hand quantum entanglement can be seen between degrees of freedom of two sub systems even if they are space-like separated (see Griffith's quantum mechanics text,). No superluminal information can be transmitted by such type of correlation as to respect s.t.r. ..I am comparing classical coherence with quantum entanglement..for quantum coherence see the link mentioned above in stack exchange..

Comment: for quantum coherence you can refer to the link mentioned in answer given in the above link ..what I have compared  is classical coherence with quantum entanglement..